# Check whether element available in the ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, contains

I have an ArrayList and I've added elements to the ArrayList using `mylist.add()` method.

I've added around 10 elements and now I want to figure out whether an element *is available* in the ArrayList, if so what is the *index position*. How can I acheive this?? the contains method doesn't help.

I searched online but couldn't figure out a tutorial, may be i'm missing the correct keywords in the search

Thanks for your time in advance.

Comment: You can see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986924/best-way-to-use-contains-in-an-arraylist-in-java

Comment: And this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769797/arraylist-of-my-objects-indexof-problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int pos = myList.indexOf(myElement);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.contains()` to test whether an element is in the `ArrayList`, but it sounds like you want `.indexOf()` which will return the index of that Object.

See: [http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29)

Answer (score 1):

have a look at [ArrayList.indexOf()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29) [specified by List interface]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are looking for indexOf, returns -1 if no element present, see

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)

Answer (score 1):

The following should do the trick:

```
int index = myList.indexOf(myObject);  // Returns -1 if not present.
```