# Search through Java collection using class attribute

Tags: java, search, collections

I have an abstract class like this:

```
public abstract class Ingredient {
    protected int id;
}
```

and a list

```
List <Ingredient> ingredientList = new ArrayList <Ingredient>()
```

I want to be able to get an Ingredient from the `ingredientList` using id.

I did something like this:

```
public abstract class Ingredient implements Comparable<Ingredient>{
        protected int id;
        @Override
    public int compareTo(Ingredient o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (this.id > o.id){
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    }
```

but still not working

Comment: And, whats stopping you from doing so? Whats your question?

Comment: And what is the expected result of such a search?

Comment: i did this in the past using something i think "comparator" or "comparable", I'm searching to do it now but not being able to, its just implementing an interface "comparable" and doing something, i'm not getting it

Comment: You can implement 'comparable' and compare the instances using the id in the compareTo() method. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Proably you should add some explanation in natural language

Answer (score 2):

If you need to perform regular lookups, a `Map` is probably a better collection to use here:

```
Map<Integer, Ingredient> ingredientMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for (Ingredient ingredient : IngredientList) {
  if (ingredient.getId() == id) {
    System.out.println("found");
  }
}
System.out.println("not found");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/) you can use the detect method.

```
final int idToFind = ...;
ListIterable<Ingredient> ingredientList = FastList.newListWith(...);
Ingredient ingredient = ingredientList.detect(new Predicate<Ingredient>()
{
    public boolean accept(Ingredient eachIngredient)
    {
        return eachIngredient.getId() == idToFind;
    }
});
```

If you cant change the type of ingredientList, you can still use the static utility form of detect.

```
Ingredient ingredient = ListIterate.detect(ingredientList, new Predicate<Ingredient>()
{
    public boolean accept(Ingredient eachIngredient)
    {
        return eachIngredient.getId() == idToFind;
    }
});
```

When Java 8 is released lambdas, you will be able to shorten the code to:

```
Ingredient ingredient = ingredientList.detect(eachIngredient -> eachIngredient.getId() == idToFind);
```

**Note:** I am a committer for Eclipse collections.

Answer (score 0):

you can do (within you class)

```
interface Callback { public void handle(Indredient found); }

public void search(List<Ingredient> ingredientList, int id, Callback callback) { 
  for(Ingredient i : ingredientList) if(i.id == id) callback.handle(i)
}
```

and then

```
ingredients.search ( 10, new Callback() { 
       public void handle(Ingredient found) {
            System.out.println(found);
       }
   });
```

or something similar...

ps.: i answered before you changed you question ;)

Comment: Why bother messing with a callback, rather than just returning?

Comment: returning what?  he did not specify, what .. all or one matching

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but could it be that this is what you mean:

[Best way to use contains in an ArrayList in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986924/best-way-to-use-contains-in-an-arraylist-in-java)

contains() method of list uses equals() and hashCode()

Answer (score 0):

When you use `List.contains()` to find the Ingredient with id, then override  `equals()` and `hashCode() { return id};`

In equals(): in equal compare this.id with other.id .

Answer (score 0):

```
public Ingredient getIngredientById(int id) {
   for (Ingredient ingredient : ingredientList) {
      if (ingredient.id == id) {
         return ingredient;
      }
   }
}
```